# How to user android:digits programmatically

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am currently using

```
android:digits="qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnmQWERTZUIOPASDFGHJKLYXCVBNM "
```

in android XML in EditText and it is working perfectly. The user can enter only characters from a-z,A-Z and space(I don't want to allow the user to enter numbers or special characters). I would like to add this property to another Edit Text field programaticaly. Can anyone help me to add the above property programmaticaly. I have referred the following links but its of no use

[Change android:digits programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871561/change-androiddigits-programatically)
[How to block special characters in androids editText? no ANDROID:DIGITS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906744/how-to-block-special-characters-in-androids-edittext-no-androiddigits)

if I use

```
edtTxt.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnmQWERTZUIOPASDFGHJKLYXCVBNM"));
```

numeric keypad is getting opened.

Comment: Have you tried only `EdiText.setInputType
    (InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set EditText Digits Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300490/set-edittext-digits-programmatically)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the code below

```
edtTxt.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        edtTxt.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{
                new InputFilter() {
                    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence src, int start,
                                               int end, Spanned dst, int dstart, int dend) {
                        if (src.equals("")) {
                            return src;
                        }
                        if (src.toString().matches("[a-zA-Z ]+")) {
                            return src;
                        }
                        return "";
                    }
                }
        });
```

Comment: I have done it just before you have posted the answer. However as it works. I have accepted the answer :)

Comment: This is not the actual answer to the question, this seems like a hacky way, DigitsKyeListener should be able to do the work what is expected with `android:digits` property.